# dir command output different results between local dirves and network drives

Tags: cmd

I just test a piece of cmd on my computer:

```
C:\Users\user>dir D:\test\*.xls /b
test - copy.xls
test - copy.xlsx
test.xls
test.xlsx

C:\Users\user>dir Y:\test\*.xls /b
test - copy.xls
test.xls
```

The two `test` file fold is absolutely the same. Dirve "D" is a local dirve and dirve "Y" is a network dirve. I checked the version of my machine and the source machine of dirve "Y", they were different indeed. Here are my questions:

1. I only plan to run my program on local machine, is there an option to always output the second results?
2. If it is "No" to question 1, may I add some option like `-*.xlsx` to remove `*.xlsx` results from my program?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can exclude `*.xlsx` like this:

```
dir D:\test\*.xls /b | findstr /v /i "\.xlsx$"
```

Will exclude even xls.* too:

```
dir D:\test\*.xls /b | findstr /v /i "\.xls.$"
```

Comment: This, in my opinion, does not really answer the question asked. Yes, it will exclude the `.xlsx` files, but what happens if there are `.xlsm` files, or other files whose extensions begin with `.xls`, but do not end with `.xls`, there too!

Comment: @Compo i have inserted also another regex which will exclude any character after .xls at the end of string

Answer (score 1):

Obviously on your local computer short 8dot3 file names are enabled.
You can see that when running dir /x ...
There are different ways to generate 8dot3 file names. Usually an extension with more than three letters is truncated, e.g
.xlxs leads to .XLS
The dir command always searches in both long filenames and 8dot3 file names.

You have some options to change that behaviour:

1. Disable 8dot3 file names. This may be done with fsutil.exe, either per drive or for the complete system.
2. Change the way how 8dot3 file names are generated in the registry.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"Win95TruncatedExtensions"=dword:00000000
```

In this case .xlsx would lead to .XL~

Note:
When you do any of these changes, it works first for newly created files.
For older files you should copy them.
But when you want to disable all 8dot3 file names you can use fsutil.exe to strip 8dot3 file names in older files.